# Python function working only when used first time

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am learning python and working on a dataframe.
What I am trying to do is to convert the date+time in the dataframe into a timestamp (it is a work in progress, I think what I am doing right now is not the most elegant way).

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df = pd.read_csv(path, skiprows = 2)

In [3]: df
Out[3]:
                               VariableKey  %CO2
    0      2020-06-16T12:41:46.0262558         1.309835
    1      2020-06-16T12:41:57.7774632         4.796404
    2      2020-06-16T12:42:09.8411340         9.658635

In [4]: def time (x):
            dx = x['VariableKey'].str.replace("T", " ")
            n = x.shape[0]
            for row in range(0, n):
                x.iloc[row, 0] = pd.to_datetime(x.iloc[row, 0])
            return dx

In [5]: time(df)
Out[5]:
0        2020-06-16 12:41:46.0262558
1        2020-06-16 12:41:57.7774632
2        2020-06-16 12:42:09.8411340
3        2020-06-16 12:42:21.8733120
```

Until now everything was alright, but I get an issue I do not understand.

If I re-enter a second time:

```
time(df)
```

I have:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-860c8fa24431> in <module>
----> 1 time(df)

<ipython-input-8-d2ea2de6dbdb> in time(x)
      1 def time (x):
----> 2     dx = x['VariableKey'].str.replace("T", " ")
      3     n = x.shape[0]
      4     for row in range(0, n):
      5         x.iloc[row, 0] = pd.to_datetime(x.iloc[row, 0])

c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\strings.py in wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1952                 )
   1953                 raise TypeError(msg)
-> 1954             return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1955
   1956         wrapper.__name__ = func_name

c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\strings.py in replace(self, pat, repl, n, case, flags, regex)
   2775     def replace(self, pat, repl, n=-1, case=None, flags=0, regex=True):
   2776         result = str_replace(
-> 2777             self._parent, pat, repl, n=n, case=case, flags=flags, regex=regex
   2778         )
   2779         return self._wrap_result(result)

c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\strings.py in str_replace(arr, pat, repl, n, case, flags, regex)
    724         f = lambda x: x.replace(pat, repl, n)
    725
--> 726     return _na_map(f, arr, dtype=str)
    727
    728

c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\strings.py in _na_map(f, arr, na_result, dtype)
    129     if na_result is None:
    130         na_result = np.nan
--> 131     return _map_object(f, arr, na_mask=True, na_value=na_result, dtype=dtype)
    132
    133

c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\strings.py in _map_object(f, arr, na_mask, na_value, dtype)
    214         convert = not np.all(mask)
    215         try:
--> 216             result = lib.map_infer_mask(arr, f, mask.view(np.uint8), convert)
    217         except (TypeError, AttributeError) as e:
    218             # Reraise the exception if callable `f` got wrong number of args.

pandas\_libs\lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer_mask()

c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\strings.py in <lambda>(x)
    714             f = lambda x: compiled.sub(repl=repl, string=x, count=n)
    715         else:
--> 716             f = lambda x: x.replace(pat, repl, n)
    717     else:
    718         if is_compiled_re:

pandas\_libs\tslibs\timestamps.pyx in pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp.replace()

pandas\_libs\tslibs\timestamps.pyx in pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp.replace.validate()

ValueError: value must be an integer, received <class 'str'> for year
```

On the first time the function always works but once it has been used, no.
It does not really make any sense to me as from my point of view, as long as my dataframe do not change, same causes should have same effects. If someone has any idea? Edit: Better understand it now, Thank you all for the helpfull answers!

Comment: Aren't you doing an in-place conversion there, so the df no longer contains a string?

Comment: You seem to be substituting in place [row, 0]. The first time it's probably a string, but the second time is something else. A datetime, maybe (in any case: different types between calls) Sorry I'm not very knowledgeable in Pandas to help further

Comment: Your function does not edit dx, it's editing x

Answer (score 1):

you are changing your dataframe inside the time function, to avoid that, you could do

```
def time (x):
     x = x.copy() #make copy of the data
     dx = x['VariableKey'].str.replace("T", " ")
     x.iloc[:, 0] = pd.to_datetime(x.iloc[:, 0])
     return dx
```

now it should work, even though I don't see the point of converting the data to datetime if you are not even returning it, so my duggestion to you is to do instead:

```
def time (x):
     dx = x['VariableKey'].str.replace("T", " ")
     return pd.to_datetime(dx)
```

or yet better:

```
time = lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x['VariableKey'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You converted `x["VariableKey"]` to str when you called the function for the first time that is when on second call year is a string instead of an integer (which is expected)

Answer (score 0):

```
# you can compare with df(before time(df)) and df(after time(df))

print(df['VariableKey'].map(lambda x:type(x)).unique()) # type of values of VariableKey; maybe it is "str"

time(df)  # after all method "time"

print(df['VariableKey'].map(lambda x:type(x)).unique())  # it would be "datetime"
# yes, when you call "time(df)", the values of df was changed!
```